# Is this the most efficient way to write the Luhn algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, luhn

This is my code for the Luhn algorithm (credit card checker). Is it good...

```
card = raw_input("Enter your credit card number here: ")
card = list(str(card))
card = [int(x) for x in card]
check = card[-1]
del(card[-1])
card[::2] = [2*x for x in card[::2]]
for i, x in enumerate(card):
        card[i] = sum(map(int, str(x)))
card = sum(card) * 9
card = list(str(card))
card = [int(x) for x in card]
if card[-1] == check:
    print("Card is valid!")
else:
    print("Card is invalid!")
```

Or can I make it shorter/more efficient?

Comment: That’s an extremely strange way of writing it, and it’s definitely not the most efficient one. How about using one loop?

Comment: How is it strange? It iterates through each step clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re computing the value of the check digit to check a number, but you don’t have to do that. The point of the check digit is that it produces a particular result – a number divisible by 10 – when combined with the rest of the numbers.

You can do it all in one loop and no intermediate lists, and the easiest way to explain that is this:

```
card = raw_input("Enter your credit card number here: ")
digit_sum = 0

for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(card)):
    n = int(digit)

    if i % 2 == 0:
        digit_sum += n
    elif n >= 5:
        digit_sum += n * 2 - 9
    else:
        digit_sum += n * 2

if digit_sum % 10 == 0:
    print("Card is valid!")
else:
    print("Card is invalid!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Function test card number under Luhn algorithm:

```
def Luhn(card_number):
    sum = 0
    num_digits = len(card_number)
    oddeven = num_digits & 1
    for count in range(0, num_digits):
        digit = int(card_number[count])
        if not (( count & 1 ) ^ oddeven ):
            digit = digit * 2
        if digit > 9:
            digit = digit - 9
        sum = sum + digit
    if sum % 10 == 0:
        print("Card is valid!")
    else:
        print("Card is invalid!")
```